# Android animation linearlayout

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, objectanimator

I have got a linearlayout form. This form has got a 2 fields. I would like get this effect:

Two fields, one is hidden (under top bar). When i click button 'ok' this linear layout go down and display next field (hidden field). How get this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place your two fields inside a `RelativeLayout`.
- Set the property `android:visibility="gone"` for the first of them.
- Set the property `android:layout_below="@id/yourFirstField"` for the second.
- Add `onClickListener` to the button and, in the body on the listener in your Java class, change the visibility of the first field to visible (I guess it's an EditText, so `EditText.VISIBLE`)
- If you want to get a nice effect for hiding/showing elements, add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your RelativeLayout (the container of both items).

This should work!! I hope this helps!!

Comment: But i try with object animation and used negativ margin to hidden linearlayout